# stopPropagation() for a KeyboardEvent

Tags: javascript

**Question**

How can I successfully prevent a KeyboardEvent from bubbling, without doing a `return false` immediately in the event handler?

Note: the event is of type `KeyboardEvent` and I'm *not* using jQuery, so `e.stopPropagation()` is not an option (there's not such method on the `KeyboardEvent` object when I `console.log` it).

**More info**

The events are bound using native methods (`addEventListener()` or `attachEvent()`, depending on the browser), and the defaults are canceled using this function:

```
this.cancelHandler = function(event) {
    /**
     * Cross browser event cancellation (e.preventDefault() is not available without jQuery 
     */

    var e = event || window.event;
    // All good browsers…
    if (e.preventDefault) {e.preventDefault();}
    // …and IE
    if (e.returnValue) {e.returnValue = false;}

    return false;
};
```

That *prevents* the defaults from firing, but it doesn't stop propagation for those `KeyboardEvent`s.

I'm looking for something compatible with *at least* IE7+ and modern browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Use this piece of code

```
e.cancelBubble = true;
if( e.stopPropagation ) e.stopPropagation();
```

stopPropagation is NOT jQuery, but standard function ( certainly NOT ie standard )

Comment: This seemed to me as the correct solution too (something like: `if (typeof e.cancelBubble === 'boolean') { e.cancelBubble = true; }`, in case some old browser doesn't have this property). Unfortunately, it didn't solve my scenario. However, I found a "hacky" way: delay the code inside the event handler that *also* listens to `keydown`,  using `setTimeout`. This way, the event bubbles down and is gone long before the code that will listen to future events executes. (Nasty though, it should be possible to register more listeners but prevent current event from bubbling...)